# What kind of sites will be covered in JMeter for performance/load testing?

Tags: jmeter

I have started learning JMeter. One question arise in my mind that what kind of sites we can test using Jmeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and dynamic resources (Webservices (SOAP/REST), Web dynamic languages - PHP, Java, ASP.NET, Files, etc. -, Java Objects, Data Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more)